# For what values of $x$ does $x^2 \in\mathbb{ N}$ imply $x \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis

For what values of $x$ does $x^2 \in\mathbb{ N}$ imply $x \in \mathbb{Q}$?

My approach: Clearly $x$ can not be irrational. Let $x=\dfrac{p}{q}$ where $\text{gcd}(p,q)=1$. Since $x^2\in\mathbb{N}$, $q^2$ must divide $p^2$. But as $\text{gcd}(p,q)=1$, it follows that $q^2=1$ or $q=\pm1$. So $x\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Why do you rule out $x=0$?

Comment: I did not find any problem with what you wrote.

Comment: @Slugger, I thought since $0\notin\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @hgkj Depending upon places in the world, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ or not. :-)

Comment: Normally, we choose $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: @hgkj Fair enough, was just curious that I didn't miss anything :)

Comment: According to the Peano axioms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms $0\in\mathbb{N}$. But this is actually irrelevant for your argument, which is correct. With a slightly bigger effort and reasoning along the same lines you should prove that if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ satisfies a relation of the form $x^r+a_1x^{r-1}+\cdots+a_r$ where each $a_j\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.